# Seeking scheme for readonly viewing email messages, i.e. *.eml

Tags: email

Because I used helm's helm-source-mac-spotlight I often get email files in my result lists.  This is great.  It often surfaces old discussions about the issue I'm working on.

But, these files have the raw message in them.  Plenty of headers and mime parts.

I don't do my mail handling in emacs usually.  It's been decades since I last set up a reasonable system for doing that.

I'm seeking a more friendly view the *.eml files.

I did notice that people often set the .eml files to have mail-mode or mail-message-mode, but neither of these appear to lead to a friendly end result.

Suggestions?

Comment: How about just displaying them in an external mail application?  On OS X, for example, it might look like this:  `(start-process "my-process" nil "open" "/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.eml")`

Comment: Take a look at the mu4e package.